# Argument checks best practices

Tags: python

I have a simple code that needs at least 1 argument. Right now my code format looks something like this:

```
import modules 

# argparse stuff
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(-m)
parser.add_argument(-u)
args = parser.parse_args()

# check the number of arguments 
if len(sys.argv) > 3:
sys.exit()

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
sys.exit()

class Program:
      def A():
      def B():
      def C():

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
       Program()
```

The code works as intended, but I'd like to know how I can rewrite my code to be 'pythonic'. Do I put the argument checks under the 'if **name**' statement? If so, how? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not looking at sys.argv, especially if you're already using a CLI parsing library.

Argprase has a pile of ways to enforce requirements, but if none of those fit your needs you can looks at your 'args' object.

Personally, I would suggest not running functions, like parse_args(), in the global scope of that file. Instead I would suggest (at minimum) to just wrap what you've got in a function called main, then call 'main()' after 'if __name__ == '__main__'

Argparse examples:

if '-m' and '-u' are mutually exclusive

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('-m')
group.add_argument('-u')

args = parser.parse_args()  # will output a error message if '-m' or '-u' isn't supplied
```

If a specific arg is required always

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-m', required=True)   # must always give '-m'
```

Or just looking at the 'args' object

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-m')
parser.add_argument('-u')

args = parser.parse_args()
if not (args.m or args.u):
    sys.exit(1) # should exit non-zero on failures
```

main wrapping example:

```
import modules

class Program:
      def A():
      def B():
      def C():

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(-m)
    parser.add_argument(-u)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if not (args.m or args.u):
        sys.exit(1)

    try:
       Program()
    except SomeException:
        # handle it
        pass # b/c I don't know what you need here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the number of arguments after `argparse` doesn't make much sense. If there's some error, `argparse` will handle that, so you don't really have to replicate it.

Do put the arguments check after `if __name__` check - just in case you want to import the module without executing.

Otherwise, it's just standard code as you'd see in `argparse` documentation. Nothing really wrong with it.